# Que cosas son las hay que definir como clases - POO

Tags: python, poo

Quiero empezar a aplicar el concepto de POO en mis programas para que sean más profesionales. Conceptualmente creo que me queda claro, ahora me falta ponerlo en práctica para coger soltura.

La cosa es que en los típicos ejemplos educativos, la idea es bastante sencilla, pero no soy capaz de extrapolarlo a mis programas.

A continuación dejo mi código el cual querría convertir (las partes que lo precisen) a clases.

```
def main():
    # 1. Obtengo datos de los diferentes ficheros csv
    data = pd.read_csv('data/marcas.csv')
    marcas = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data = pd.read_csv('data/ejercicios.csv')
    ejs = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data = pd.read_csv('data/wod.csv')
    wod = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data = pd.read_csv('data/wod_ejs.csv')
    wod_ejs = pd.DataFrame(data)
    shape = wod_ejs.shape

    print('Hay',shape[0],'WODs registrados')

    # 2. Preparo las marcas pues las voy a trabajar seguro
    marcas_padres = marcas.to_dict('records')

    # 3. Filtro wods a mostrar (si no se defien, se muestran todos)
    #wod = wod[(wod['cap'] == 30) & (wod['material'] == True)]
    #wod = wod[wod['material'] == 'false']

    # 4. Preparo los datos de los wods seleccionados
    wod_d = wod.to_dict('records')
    print('Hay %d WODs con esa premisa' % (len(wod)))

    # 5. Trabajo los wods seleccionados
    for r in range(len(wod_d)):
        # 5.1. Obtengo los diferentes datos del wod actual
        id = wod_d[r].get('codigo')
        v = wod_d[r].get('vueltas')
        m = str(wod_d[r].get('material')).upper()
        p = wod_d[r].get('porcentaje')
        c = wod_d[r].get('cap')
        gm = wod_d[r].get('grupo muscular').capitalize()

        print('\nWOD %d: Vueltas: %d [%d%s] - CAP: %d\' - Enfoque: %s - Material: %s - Código: %s'
              % (r+1, v, p*100, '%', c, gm, m, id))

        # 5.2. Obtengo los ejercicios del wod actual
        wod_ejs_filtered = wod_ejs[wod_ejs['codigo'] == id]
        wod_ejs_d = wod_ejs_filtered.to_dict('records')
        # 5.3. Trabajo los ejercicios del wod actual
        for x in wod_ejs_d[0]:
            # 5.3.1. Solo trabajamos los ejercicios del wod, ni su código, ni esos que contienen "#"
            if wod_ejs_d[0].get(x) != '#' and x != 'codigo':
                ej = wod_ejs_d[0].get(x)
                ej_true = ejs[ejs['nombre'] == ej]
                # 5.3.2. Comprobamos que el ejercicio esté en la lista y por lo tanto podamos trabajarlo
                match = np.all(ejs[ejs['nombre'] == ej])
                if match == True:
                    print('EL EJERCICIO %s NO APARECE EN LA LISTA' %(ej.upper()))
                else:
                    ej_true_d = ej_true.to_dict('records')
                    #esp = ej_true_d[0].get('nombre_es')
                    #mat = ej_true_d[0].get('material')
                    val = ej_true_d[0].get('valor')
                    padre = ej_true_d[0].get('padre')
                    val_padre = marcas_padres[0].get(padre)
                    reps = ceil(p * val * val_padre)
                    # En caso que el atleta no sea capaz de realizar un ejercicio, se le cambia por su antecesor con su max de reps.
                    if reps == 0:
                        ej = ej_true_d[0].get('antecesor')
                        ej_true = ejs[ejs['nombre'] == ej]
                        ej_true_d = ej_true.to_dict('records')
                        val = ej_true_d[0].get('valor')
                        padre = ej_true_d[0].get('padre')
                        val_padre = marcas_padres[0].get(padre)
                        reps = ceil(val * val_padre)
                        print('\t- %d %s (EJ MODIFICADO AL ANTECESOR)' % (reps, ej))
                    else:
                        print('\t- %d %s' %(reps,ej))

            # 5.3. En caso de obtener un "#" significa que ya no tiene más ejs el wod actual y por lo tanto se ha terminado.
            elif wod_ejs_d[0].get(x) == '#':
                break
```

Está comentado para ver si me podéis ayudar a enfocar cómo hacerlo.

Básicamente lo que hace es acudir a una serie de ficheros de datos y genera rutinas de entrenamiento. Yo creo que la clase general se podría llamar `wod()` y que a la hora de crear entrenos, de lo único que dependiera es de los "filtros" que se le aplicase. Por ejemplo, mostrar aquellos entrenos que no requieren de material (es decir, material = False), o por ejemplo, mostrar aquellos que no requieran de material y además su enfoque sea "Full body".

Eso es básicamente lo que hago en el punto 3, si no pongo nada muestra todos los entrenos que existen, y si en ese punto filtro el dataframe pues muestra aquellos entrenos que cumplen las condiciones previamente dichas.

Pero no tengo claro que crear cómo clase, que propiedades son comunes (yo no veo ninguna).

Me gustaría que el día de mañana simplemente escribiendo algo similar a lo siguiente se me ejecutase el programa.

```
wod1 = wod()
wod1.filtrar(False,'Full body',30) #Sin material, full body, cap=30
```

Los filtros podrían ser: material, cap(tiempo), enfoque. Pero bueno, esto una vez lo entienda lo podré modificar yo a mi antojo e ir añadiendo filtros o quitando.

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Técnica básica: De la descripción coloquial del problema que resuelves encuentra y enlista los **verbos**, **sujetos** y **adjetivos**. Descarta las palabras técnicas de informática -como *fichero* ó *filtro*-. De la lista de sujetos, los **sustantivos** más repetidos serán tus principales candidatos a **Clase**, los verbos relacionados sus **métodos** y los adjetivos que apliquen sus **propiedades**.

La característica **Abstracción** fundamental de la POO, nos habla de entidades (sustantivos) que son abstracciones de la **realidad**. En contraste con la programación procedural, donde la unidad fundamental es la **función**.

En tu caso, al enfocarte más en la **función de filtrado** tiendes a alejarte de la que sería tu clase principal **Entrenamiento**. Un *Filtrador de Entrenamientos* no es una abstracción de la realidad, y estarías haciendo *programación estructurada “camuflada”*.